# Core Data, filtering out child entities in result set

Tags: iphone, core-data

So I have typical 1:M relationship:

```
Car can have many Models
```

I want to get all Car objects and only Model names that begin with 'A'.

I tried a subquery:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Car" inManagedObjectContext:_context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(models, $model, $model.name BEGINSWITH 'A').@count > 0"];    
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

This would basically return a `Car` as long as it has a model that begins with 'A'.  That's fine, but for all those `Car`s returned, it also returns all the `Model`s, and I only want the ones that start with 'A'

But it seems as long as I operate on the higher level entity (Car), then that subquery only filters `Cars` and doesn't filter `Models` at all.

What I'm doing it now is filtering `Models` in an inner loop (using another `NSPredicate`), but I'd rather do this filtering on the SQL side.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your fetch against the `Models` entity with a predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name BEGINSWITH 'A'"];
```

From the result array, `NSArray *result`, you can get all of the `Cars` with KVC:

```
[result valueForKey:@"car"];
```

assuming you have 1:1 inverse relationships for your 1:M `Cars` to `Models` relationship (you should, by the way; Core Data uses inverse relationships to maintain consistency of the object graph).

If you want just the set of unique `Cars`:

```
[result valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.car"];
```

or

```
NSSet *cars = [NSSet setWithArray:[result valueForKey:@"car"]];
```

Comment: Yeah, that's something I arrived at.  Working via the Models entry first and then getting back the cars.  I like your KVC method here.
Thanks!